# Evaluate $\int \int \int_B x^2+y^2 \, dxdydz$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, bounds-of-integration

I'd like to evaluate $\int \int \int_B x^2+y^2 \, dxdydz$ where $B$ is the area enclosed by $x^2+y^2=2z$ and $z=2$ but I'm not sure about the bounds. I've thought something like this...
$$\int_0^2 \int_{-\sqrt{2z-x^2}}^{\sqrt{2z-x^2}} \int_{-\sqrt{2z-y^2}}^{\sqrt{2z-y^2}} x^2+y^2 dxdydz$$

but obviously, it won't work because I reintroduce $x$ in the second integral. Any suggestions on the bounds?

Comment: Cylindrical coordinates

Comment: At $z = 2, x^2 + y^2 \leq 4$ and that gives you bounds for $x, y$ or $r, \theta$. $z$ is bound between $(x^2 + y^2) /2$ and $2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From symmetry of the region, it is best to integrate in cylindrical coordinates $( r, \phi, z ) $

The bounds are $ z = \dfrac{1}{2} r^2 $ and $ z = 2 $

So $ r $ will range from $0$ to $ 2$.

$I = \displaystyle \int_{\phi = 0 }^{2\pi} \int_{r = 0}^{2} \int_{ z = \dfrac{1}{2} r^2 }^{2} dz r^3 dr d\phi $

Integrating with respect to $\phi$ and $z$ simplifies the above to

$I = \displaystyle 2 \pi \int_{r = 0 }^2 \left( 2 r^3 -  \dfrac{1}{2} r^5 \right) dr $

And this evaluates to

$ I = \displaystyle 2 \pi \left( \dfrac{1}{2} r^4 - \dfrac{1}{12} r^6 \right)\biggr| _{0}^{2} =   \dfrac{16 \pi}{3} $